# pythonic way to write to text files, replacing this bash command for windows

Tags: python, windows

I am working on a program for a windows 10 user. Files are created fine, but then writing to these files is problematic. It works fine on linux, but very iffy on windows. I think the way I am doing this is probably not at all how one should...

Code:

```
if not os.path.exists('config.txt'):
    Path('config.txt').touch()
    os.system('echo "None=True\nClick=False\nClick2=False\Click3=False" > config.txt')

else:
    . . .
```

Note: I have an identical code block that does this but redirects a single char into file, it works. The snippet above does not work.

I have tried removing quotation marks, but it does not work. I know I could modify the texts using with open(. . .), but I want to know if there is a better way of doing it.

Thanks

Comment: What exactly do you have to write? You can use a ```for``` loop to iterate over the files and write into them.

Comment: I just need to write the lines contained after the echo command if the user is starting this app for the first time.

Comment: Did you mean this: ```None=True\nClick=False\nClick2=False\Click3=False"```

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: The correct way of writing to a file is using `open` and it is platform independent.

Comment: That's right, but I thin @Vellutante wants to write into text file using echo.

Comment: It's totally unclear where your problems lie. Use the textbook examples for writing files unless you have a real reason not to. If you want to ask, make sure you don't just provide interpretations ("doesn't work", "very iffy") but the actual observations. Also, provide a [mcve] and the expected observations. Also, take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Got it, I will research more in the future about how to refine my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `\n` would not work so I had to add it separately.

```
import os
os.system('echo None=True > config.txt')  #=== '>' Creates a file if doesn't exist else writes into it
os.system('echo Click=False >> config.txt') #=== '>>' Appends text to the given file.
os.system('echo Click2=False >> config.txt')
os.system('echo Click3=False >> config.txt')
```